# Scala for yield loop not providing expected output

Tags: scala, collections, equals, for-comprehension

The following sample code snippet:

```
val deck = for {
  suit <- Suit.values
  rank <- Rank.values
} yield {
  println(s"$rank $suit")
  PlayingCard(suit, rank)
}
print(deck)
```

provides the following output:

> Ace Hearths
> Two Hearths
> Three Hearths
> Four Hearths
> Five Hearths
> Six Hearths
> Seven Hearths
> Eight Hearths
> Nine Hearths
> Ten Hearths
> Jack Hearths
> Queen Hearths
> King Hearths
> Ace Diamonds
> Two Diamonds
> Three Diamonds
> Four Diamonds
> Five Diamonds
> Six Diamonds
> Seven Diamonds
> Eight Diamonds
> Nine Diamonds
> Ten Diamonds
> Jack Diamonds
> Queen Diamonds
> King Diamonds
> Ace Spades
> Two Spades
> Three Spades
> Four Spades
> Five Spades
> Six Spades
> Seven Spades
> Eight Spades
> Nine Spades
> Ten Spades
> Jack Spades
> Queen Spades
> King Spades
> Ace Clubs
> Two Clubs
> Three Clubs
> Four Clubs
> Five Clubs
> Six Clubs
> Seven Clubs
> Eight Clubs
> Nine Clubs
> Ten Clubs
> Jack Clubs
> Queen Clubs
> King Clubs
>
> TreeSet(Ace of Clubs, Two of Clubs, Three of Clubs, Four of Clubs, Five of Clubs, Six of Clubs, Seven of Clubs, Eight of Clubs, Nine of Clubs, Ten of Clubs, Jack of Clubs, Queen of Clubs, King of Clubs)

I have absolutely no idea why this code correctly iterates over all cards, but only seems to return the last suit (being clubs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's because you're building a `TreeSet`, but you've implemented equality for `PlayingCard` wrong so it's discarding elements that you want to keep. This would happen if `PlayingCard.equals` only considers the rank of the card, ignoring the suit.

If `PlayingCard.equals` was implemented so that it ignores the suit then whenever you add an Ace of any suit to the `Set` it will remove the previous Ace. This seems like the problem you're seeing.

To fix this, either change the definition of `PlayingCard.equals` to consider the suit or force a different collection type that doesn't care about equality, e.g. `Vector`:

```
val deck = for {
  suit <- Suit.values.toVector
  rank <- Rank.values.toVector
} yield {
  println(s"$rank $suit")
  PlayingCard(suit, rank)
}
print(deck)
```

Comment: Wow, good catch with such limited information. I indeed implemented PlayingCard as Ordered only taking into account the rank and not the suit. I had to convert suit to vector as well to for this solution to work though. Are there any other ways to explicitly define what type of collection yield will return as this can lead to unexpected results.

Comment: When you use a for-comprehension you're going to end up using `map` and `flatMap` on the underlying collections you're iterating over. Take a look at the signatures of those methods and you'll see they take two type parameters - one is the target element type and the other is the new collection type to build. The target collection defaults to the same type, but you can set it yourself. If you call `map` and `flatMap` explicitly instead of using a for-comprehension then you can control the target collection type.